# What does discovery.seed_hosts and cluster.initial_master_nodes mean in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 7.10.1, and I am reading https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html#unicast.hosts.

I have 5 master nodes `(node.master: true node.data: false)` and 20 data nodes`(node.master: false node.data: true)`.

I got following four questions:

1. Should both `discovery.seed_hosts`  and `cluster.initial_master_nodes` be specified with the `master` nodes? I mean, could I specify the data node for these two configurations?
2. Since I have 5 master nodes in my case, how many nodes should I specify for these two configurations. I think I don't have to list all of these 5 nodes in these configurations?
3. It looks to me that `discovery.seed_hosts` is like old version elastic search's  `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts`?
4. It looks to me that `cluster.initial_master_nodes` is like old version elastics search's `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. It is recommended to add the setting in at least 3 master nodes for fault tolerance.
2. I would put all 5 to avoid confusion
3. Yes it is but will still work for legacy
4. Yes it is but will still work for legacy

Remember that cluster.initial_master_nodes is used once after the cluster bootstrapping then will be ignored and it is recommended to remove it from the configuration.

[Cluster bootstrapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-discovery-bootstrap-cluster.html)

[Cluster Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-settings.html)

In short `discovery.seed_hosts` is the list of master nodes a new node uses to join the cluster, and `cluster.initial_master_nodes` is the initial list to bootstrap a cluster.

Comment: Thanks @llermaly for the perfect explanation!

Comment: To elaborate 4th question  I want to add that `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` setting is removed in version 7.0
See (https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-new-era-for-cluster-coordination-in-elasticsearch ) for a detailed explanation.